# req.checkBody is not a function with Express-Validator NODEJS

Tags: node.js, express-validator

Hi I'm trying doing a login page, after clicking on submit I'm getting this error with express-validator version 5.3.1

```
req.checkBody is not a function
TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
    at Strategy._verify (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\config\passport.js:67:7)
    at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:369:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:370:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\routes\user.js:39:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

In my app.js I have required express-validator *with const validator = require('express-validator');//@5.3.1*
and used it with *app.use(validator());*

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport =require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const validator = require('express-validator');//@5.3.1
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const env = require('dotenv').config()
const app = express();

mongoose.connect(process.env.URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
require('./config/passport');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "key per i cookie",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ 
        mongoUrl: process.env.URI,
        autoRemove: 'disabled'
    }),
    cookie: { maxAge:30000,secure:false }
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



//verify if authenticated
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.locals.login =req.isAuthenticated();
  //access sessions through templates
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});

//routes
app.use('/',  require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/user', require('./routes/user'));


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Using this express-validator version I got this error when submit, using last express-validator version I get same error in console.
Why I'm getting this error??

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the way you are requiring it.

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
```

In your code you can make these changes and try:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');//@5.3.1
.
.
.
app.use(validationResult());
```

Note: check [this](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/5.3.1/index.html) link for more information.

Comment: With this i got same error but in console:

TypeError: validationResult is not a function